# Correctly receive data from web API but impossible to display them using Angular2/TypeScript

Tags: rest, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display the information I receive from a Web API but I think I'm missing something in my component.

The call in the service work (I receive a code 200 with all the Application)
[List of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP1gb.png)

But then, I just want to display them in the console and it doesn't fill the table.

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.getApplications();
        console.log(this.applications);
    }


getApplications() {
        this.applications = [];
        this._UCCXCiscoService.getApplications().subscribe(
            res => {
                this.applications = res;
            },
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
    }

    // Model

export interface Application {
    self: string;
    ScriptApplication: ScriptApplication;
    id: string;
    applicationName: string;
    type: string;
    description: string;
    maxsession: number;
    enabled: string;
}

export interface ScriptApplication {
    script: string;
    scriptParams: ScriptParam[];
}

export interface ScriptParam {
    name: string;
    value: string;
    type: string;
}

export interface RootObject {
    type: string;
    application: Application[];
}
```

My model is good, I'm pretty sure of that. I Think it's the method getApplications() that's wrong, but can't find why...

Thanks in advance for your help,

Florian

EDIT 1 : Code of getApplications() in my service

```
@Injectable()
export class UCCXCiscoService {

    public headers:Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,'Authorization': 'Basic User + mdp'});

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getApplications() {
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
        return this.http.get('API URL', options)
            .map(data => <Application[]> data.json().application)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Yes this method works and returns me the applications (as shown in the picture List of Applications). I didn't put the api url and the password here for privacy reason ^^'

EDIT 2 :
[getApplications() of component and the response of the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWL4e.png)

EDIT 3 :

```html
<div class="contentPage">
    <div class="pageTitleHeaderContainer">
        <div class="pageTitle">
            <span>Cisco</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="subContent">
        <message-to-user messageToUser={{messageToUser}} messageLevel={{messageLevel}}></message-to-user>

        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nom</th>

            <tr *ngFor="#application of applications">
                <td>{{application?.id}}</td>
                <td>{{application?.applicationName}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make sure that declaration of ``applications`` is outside the ``getApplications`` function

Comment: Yes it is. public applications:Application[];

Comment: possible to share plunker link replicating the issue ??

Comment: and are you getting data when console log the ``res`` in subscribe ??

Comment: I have never used Plunker (still a student) :S I put the console.long just after this.applications = data; and there is nothing shown (not even an empty array) so looks like my method doesn't fill the array...

Comment: Wanted to know if you are getting data from ``_UCCXCiscoService.getApplications()`` ?? Can you share the code of this function ??

Comment: return the data from `.map` in `getApplications()`

Comment: Is not that what I am already doing?

Comment: `.map` function simply transfer the element of observable which you got from ``http.get`` request but does not return any thing. You need to return the data like `.map(data => return  data.json().application)`.

Comment: Promises / Observables are asyncronous, it makes sense that you are getting an empty value. To be 100% sure that you effectively are getting something, do the console.log inside the `.subscribe` of `getApplications()`. If that solves the issue, just return the observable itself or use a getter instead. As far as I can tell anyway it makes perfectly sense, because you are logging the value before it may even be set.

Comment: .map can't return anything. I assume the problem come from getApplications() in my component that's call getApplications() from my service...

Comment: @briosheje I edited my post with a picture to show you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: @FlorianGuebel: `.map` is overriding the value of the response, it is returning something in that case. Anyway, the preview doesn't say much to me, please try to console.log the output of the HTTP response (in the .map). Remember that everything is **asyncronous** here, so your console.log doesn't make any sense, you need to wrap it in an observable or simply convert the observable in a promise and use `.then`. You are expecting an asyncronous call to be syncronous, which is impossible.

Comment: Also, remember that **interfaces in javascript don't exists in runtime**, so you are not literally casting the values, you are just assuming that **the http response implements your interface**, but you are just **assuming** this, it doesn't mean that it will be such, you should do a strict check if you want to be 100% sure that the response is valid.

Comment: @briosheje I get what you said, I will try to find a solution.

Comment: @echonax I didn't see that post when I did mine :S Will check it

Comment: @FlorianGuebel Hope it helps :-)

Comment: @FlorianGuebel: It's as easy as this: simply return the Observable and do what you need to do by subscribing to the observable. Alternatively, convert to Observable to a promise (chain .toPromise()) and use .then in your main ;)

Comment: @echonax I come back to you because it still doesn't work. My call to the api works fine, I receive data in xml (that I convert in json) and then, in my component, the array is undefined. I searched all the week-end but impossible to find something... If you need something, I can edit my post.

Comment: @FlorianGuebel are you still trying to console.log it inside ngOnInit?

Comment: @echonax No, I made the html page to display it, I put the code in my first post.

Comment: @FlorianGuebel are you sure that you read the link I've posted? You haven't even done what Picci wrote in the answer.

Comment: @echonax Yes, like 10 times to compare my code to it...

Comment: @FlorianGuebel I don't see the console.log inside the subscribe..

Comment: @echonax [getApplications()](http://imgur.com/a/lOpOR)

Comment: @FlorianGuebel are you trolling :-) ? Read your code carefully, the console.log is not inside the subscribe. You need to write it **after**  `this.applications = data;`

Comment: @echonax I did some ctrl+z before to undo my changes, didn't see it had remove the console.log... Sorry ^^' The array is full now ! I just need to find the error and I will be ablo to display the info :) [List](http://imgur.com/a/xDFz2)

Comment: @FlorianGuebel change ngFor to `*ngFor="let application of applications"`

Comment: @echonax add me an error.. I need to use #application, let never work :S [error](http://imgur.com/a/dfoMa)

Comment: @echonax Seems from the console.log (picture) that `applications` is actually an object that contains array `application`? Shouldn't it then be `*ngFor="let application of applications.application?"` I might be wrong tho :D

Comment: @FlorianGuebel try `#application of applications.application` :)

Comment: @AJT_82 good catch!

Comment: The same ngFor works perfectly for other array. But yeah, looks like I receive xml and not json.

Comment: @AJT_82 My array is not filled anymore if I do what you said [Error 2](http://imgur.com/a/hCDuf). Sorry guys, I'm new in Angular and Typescript, I might miss something stupid...

Comment: @FlorianGuebel Sorry, you need to use safe navigation operator...try `#application of applications?.application`

Comment: @FlorianGuebel Haha. Well it was a joined effort :) Just to explain a little your `applications` is an object, so the safe navigation operator safeguards null values: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator You can prepare yourself to use `?` quite a lot here in the asynchronous world :P

Comment: @AJT_82 Yeah I can't add Echonax but thanks to him too ! I never used "?" cause before, all my call in my other service were to a local database, and looked like I didn't have to use it ^^' Sorry for my english, not my first language :)

Comment: Florian, we could let @echonax write up an answer, which you could then accept, so we get an explanatory answer of what was going on here and how to fix it, so that it can be useful to others. So, hop,hop echonax, my good sir, start scratching down an answer ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 Yup he deserves some reputation

Answer (score 1):

Yor are printing on the console in the ngOnInit() method, i.e. before the subscription code is executed and therefore before the applications property is filled.
Move console.log() method inside the arrow function of subscribe() just after this.applications = res;

Comment: I dit it, still i get an empty array.

Comment: Are you sure you get data from the remote servise?

Comment: Yes, i get a code 200 with the list of the applications.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot of the data returned, it seems you are receiving data in an xml format (not JSON). So I am not sure in this case what you get out of `data.json()`. What do you see if you print on the console `console.log(data.json())`?

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the community, I found my problem. First the console.log() wasn't in the right place. Then I needed to change the ngFor to display the info and now it works fine !

You can read the comment of my post, to find the answer.